# OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration process template mismatch error

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

When trying to migrate from TFS 2010 to Visual Studio Online we are getting the error "Template Customization or Template Mismatch error". We know there have been a few customizations like adding more choices to dropdowns but don't know which ones or if there are other changes. A few people here suggested applying an uncustomized template to the projects in TFS but it's not clear which templates should be applied.

We have a project that uses the CMMI template but there are three versions of this on the TFS server - 4.0, 4.2 and 5.0. I don't see any way to tell which one was used to create the project. As a matter of fact the only reason I know it's CMMI is it errored when I created a project in Visual Studio Online with the Agile template and tried to migrate to that.

To add to the confusion, VSO only has templates with version 2013.3 so the project I'm migrating to uses the CMMI 2013.3 template. Should I add the older templates to Visual Studio Online and create my project using the same template?

Which template should I apply to the project to make it able to migrate? Should it be one of these or should I use the 2013.3 template?

Lastly, how do I get a copy of the uncustomized templates? Do I need to create a new project and export it?

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: We tried creating a new project in TFS and migrating that but it failed with the same error. We tried importing the workitems types from 2013.3 into TFS and got this error on several types. "TF26038: Field type for System.Description does not match the existing type. It was Plain Text, but now is HTML.

Comment: It looks like the field type is the issue. I found something that says when you upgrade to TFS 2012 it changes the description fields to HTML for you. I'm trying to get some hardware so that we can upgrade a copy of our TFS database to 2013 (why not go all the way) to test this. Can anyone confirm that I'm on the right path?

Comment: Please send us the logs created by the utility from the following location "C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs" to ovsmu@opshub.com and we can deduce the actual reason of this error

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CMMI process template from either TFS 2010, TFS 2012, or TFS 2013 with the OpsHub TFS to Visual Studio Online Migration Utility. It will attempt to move either of those three to Visual Studio Online's version of the CMMI process template.

You can use the [TFS Team Project Manager on CodePlex](https://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/) to help you in [comparing your team project's process template](https://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/documentation#WorkItemConfigurationCompare) with a baseline CMMI process template to help you find the differences. You can create a default CMMI team project on a new TFS server and compare against your current team project.

[image: Comparing Process Templates with TFS Team Project Manager]

[image: Comparing Work Items with TFS Team Project Manager]

Comment: Hi Ed,
Thanks for pointing me to this tool. I had tried using it but was getting errors running it. Since you suggested it I downloaded the source and was able to get it running.
However it doesn't seem to help me much. Since I've imported the WI types into my TFS 2012 project it says everything is 100% the same except for the new fields. I've imported those fields and I'm still having issues.
Unfortunately OpsHub doesn't give me any information about what's gone wrong. There are a few log files but all they have is startup info.
Any other ideas?
Thanks,
Bill

Comment: You may want to reach out to an ALM Consulting team to dive in more deeply to your Team Foundation Server.